# SignTool signing exe with underscores changes Program Name

Tags: windows-installer, code-signing, digital-signature, signtool

I am trying to use the signtool to digitally sign an executable.

Prior to signing, when double clicking to run the exe, it requests administrator privileges, and displays the Program Name as MyProgram_5.4.5.

After signing with the signtool, the admin privileges screen displays the Program Name as "5.4.5" with the text prior to the underscore missing.

Is there any way around getting the first part cut off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sign an application the admin privileges picks up the "Description" from the digital signature and displays this in the dialog. You need to set this information when you sign the executable. Another quick suggestion. I have found KSign to be much easier to use than signtool. You can find it here (it's free):

http://codesigning.ksoftware.net

Comment: The Product name is set.  When I Right Click - Properties - Details, I see Product name "MyProgram_5.4.5"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Not thinking to clearly. The name that is displayed  there is the digital signature description. I am amending my post to correct it.

Comment: Are you using signtool with command line parameters or with the wizard?

Comment: Command-line parameters, it is using whatever is in the File Description field. Is there any way to change the field to Product Name?

Comment: You would have to add /d "MyProgram 5.4.5" to the command line. The tool doesn't support reading the product name from the version information.